# Suppose A is n by n matrix such that $Au=\lambda_1 u$ and $A^T v=\lambda_2 v$ ($\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$). Prove that $u.v=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$$Au=\lambda_1 u$$
$$Au-\lambda_1 u=0$$
$$(A-\lambda_1 I)u=0$$

and

$$|A-\lambda_1I|=0$$

Doing the same for another equation:
$$(A^T-\lambda_2I)v=0$$
and
$$|A^T-\lambda_2 I|=0$$
$$|A-\lambda_2 I|^T=0$$
$$|A-\lambda_2 I|=0$$

Is what I wrote even useful to solve the question?

Comment: No it is not. Hint: prove that $(\lambda_1u).v=u.(\lambda_2v).$

Comment: This holds on $\Bbb R,$ not $\Bbb C,$ and the inner product $u\cdot v$ is $u^Tv.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be an $n×n$ matrix for some positive integer $n$. We are given, for some vectors $u,v$ of length $n$, the equations $Au=\lambda_1u$ and $A^{\top}v =\lambda_2v$, with $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ *distinct* scalars. Then we show:

**Claim:** $u^{\top}v = v^{\top}u = 0$.

*Proof:* We next show that both equations $u^{\top}A^{\top}v =\lambda_1u^{\top}v$ and $u^{\top}A^{\top}v =\lambda_2u^{\top}v$ hold.

On the one hand: $$u^{\top}A^{\top}v = (Au)^{\top}v  = \lambda_1u^{\top}v.$$ Thus indeed, the equation $u^{\top}A^{\top}v = \lambda_1u^{\top}v$ holds.

On the other hand: $$u^{\top}A^{\top}v = u^{\top}(A^{\top}v) = u^{\top}\lambda_2v = \lambda_2u^{\top}v.$$ Thus indeed, the equation $u^{\top}A^{\top}v = \lambda_2u^{\top}v$ also holds $.$

So the equations $u^{\top}A^{\top}v = \lambda_1u^{\top}v$ and $u^{\top}A^{\top}v = \lambda_2u^{\top}v$ put together, yield  the equation $\lambda_1u^{\top}v = \lambda_2u^{\top}v$, with $\lambda_1 \not = \lambda_2$. Can you finish from here, noting that the only way this is possible is if $u^{\top}v$ is $0$. This implies $v^{\top}u=(u^{\top}v)^{\top}$ is also $0$, as claimed.■

Comment: It was a duplicate.

Comment: Hi @AnneBauval I am not positive whether the trick to solving it was presented there explicitly in the link, I put this as Community Wiki as a compromise.

Comment: I don't understand why you "rolled back" to delete my (minor but not contemptible) [style improvement, which avoided double transpose](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4669787/2) (it matched my initial hint in comment). The "Community Wiki" is an invitation to improve posts, so what is the problem?

Comment: You answered my comment only by an edit of this community wiki answer, but since this edit did not take advantage of my prior improvements, I included them again.

Comment: ? These (now two) plain rollbacks are not really a "consideration". Again: my [reiterated proposal of imrovement](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4669787/5): 1) avoid your double transpose, 2) treat the OP's inner product "$u.v$" as it is (i.e. $u^\top v$) instead of converting it into the (equal but less usual) $v^\top u.$ I presented my arguments, for the interest of our community. What are yours, "please", for such a personal "preference"?

Comment: 1. I also used transpose, but not *double* transpose. 2. The notation $u.v$ is ambiguous but its usual interpretation is $u^\top v.$ 3. Rather feel ashamed than sorry, for refusing to provide the best to this site. Again: "please", what are your arguments for this (exclusively personal) "preference"? "thanks".

Comment: Double transpose is correct of course, but not necessary, as proved in my proposal. So, avoiding it is undoubtedly an improvement. This is a fact, not a personal opinion. What other argument do you have for your very personal "preference"? Can you please *explain objectively*?

Comment: You don't see why? I gave you the 2 reasons (which are purely technical, not of ego), both in comments when editing this answer, and here above. "You are insisting" as well. "When you write your community wikis, you get to write it your way": it is exactly the opposite. [Community wikis](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) are an invitation for everyone to improve the post, and a relinquishment of "property".

Comment: I gave you the 2 (objective, technical, undoubtful) reasons why they are an improvement. Can you explain to everyone why you believe they are not?

Comment: Fine, finally! A bit lengthy, and you left a useless mention of $v^\top u$ (twice: in the claim and in the last sentence), but this is a peccadillo against which I won't fight.